# Unable to set div style from codebehind

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

i have a set of radiobuttons and few of them i have inside a div tag. upon some condition i have to set this div display to none from server side(.ascx.cs file).

i have tried using this "`divname.Attributes.Add("style","display:none");`" it works for individual input elements but not working for div.

```
<div id="rdcontrol" runat="server" style="display:block">
    <asp:radiobutton id="rd" text="temp" runat="server"/>
    <asp:radiobutton id="rd1" text="temp1" runat="server"/>
</div>
```

codebehind:

```
if(condition)
{
    rdcontrol.Attributes.Add("style","display:none");
}
```

expected: the div should not be displayed.

actual: the div is displayed. when i check through inspect element the div looks like this

```
<div id="rdcontrol" style/>
```

just a style attribute with nothing (neither block nor none)

Comment: Ever heard of the `Visible` property. This is one of the most basic properties in webforms? Did you read any tutorials?

Comment: @VDWWD visible will hide the div but the space allocated will still be present, so going for display

Comment: Space allocated? You won't see it on the sreen so it has no space allocated. Or do you want to show it again with jquery at some point. Then it would make sense.

Comment: Thanks maik. and @VDWWD i have added a code snippet below with both display none and visibility hidden, you can see that with display none next content appears next to the previous content but with hidden property that content is just hidden but space stays and next content cant take that space. so looking for the solution through display styling.

Answer (score 1):

You can try another method. You can do something like this.

```
if (condition) {
   element.style.display = "none"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by behind file? You can set up a fiddle if the example isnt working. We can tackle the problem from there.

Answer (score 0):

```html
ex 1 <div style="display: none;">display</div> content after display none..<br />
ex 2 <div style="visibility: hidden;">visibility</div> content after visibility hidden.<br />
```